# Enterprise WSDL, fields that are Date in SF, came over as Calendar in Java object classes

Tags: java, date, wsdl, calendar, wsc

I used WSC-23.jar to convert enterprise WSDL file into a JAR.  While the WSDL file had the Date fields/elements correctly marked with the **type="xsd:date"**, generated Java classes for the SF objects have Date AND Datetime fields both of type Calendar.

Please advise what I need to do to generate correct Java classes.

Update: i thought that maybe i missed that java.util.date was deprecated in java 7, but it's not.

Update 2: Keith, thanks.  Found the class where this mapping is set, and will modify it to be a Date not a Calendar:  TypeMapper.java

```
private static HashMap<QName, String> getXmlJavaMapping() {
    HashMap<QName, String> map = new HashMap<QName, String>();
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "string"), String.class.getName());
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "int"), int.class.getName());
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "long"), long.class.getName());
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "float"), float.class.getName());
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "boolean"), boolean.class.getName());
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "date"), Calendar.class.getName());   // HERE IT IS
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "dateTime"), Calendar.class.getName());
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "time"), Time.class.getName());
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "base64Binary"), "byte[]");
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "double"), double.class.getName());
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "decimal"), double.class.getName());
    map.put(new QName(Constants.SCHEMA_NS, "anyType"), Object.class.getName());
    for (SfdcApiType type : SfdcApiType.values()) {
        map.put(new QName(type.getNamespace(), "ID"), String.class.getName());
        map.put(new QName(type.getNamespace(), "QueryLocator"), String.class.getName());
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a brief look at the WSC source code such as https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc/blob/91fcfd97e7e87d2f0d64a32492b0592469c079a6/src/main/java/com/sforce/ws/bind/DateCodec.java the use of Calendar appears to be a fixed design decision in WSC.

When I have used WSC I've just used Java's `Calendar` interface methods such as `getTime()` that returns a `Date` and code like this to set a `Date`:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.clear();
c.setTime(d);
sob.setField(c);
```

and lived with it.

Comment: Great call, I should have looked in the source code for wsc.  Found where it sets it - class name is TypeMapper.java